# MySQL join two completely identical tables with WHERE

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, union

I have two of same tables with different names. The first one's name is "folders" and the second one is "folders_archive". 
I like to INNER JOIN this two tables with thier full content by filtering it on a date. If I use two single query's, thats works fine, but the joined query has no result.

I like something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM folders 
INNER JOIN folders_archiv  
 ON folders_archiv.id= folders.id  
WHERE folders_archiv.datum = '".$year."-".$month."-".$day."'  
AND folders.datum = '".$year."-".$month."-".$day."';
```

I'm trying to connect these tables in several way, but something is wrong with my logic, please help to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the result should be.

Comment: My guess is that you need a union, not a join.

Comment: share two tables data and what you from that

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, by i think you need **Union** - gives you all records from two table without repeat(if repeat is acceptable use **union all**). For example:

```
select t1.* from (
SELECT column_names 
FROM folders 
UNION
SELECT column_names 
FROM folders_archive) t1
WHERE t1.column_names = what_you_want;
```

Comment: It's generally better to put the `WHERE` clause in the queries in the `UNION`, rather than filtering after combining them.

Answer (score -1):

Very vague question.

But try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM folders 
INNER JOIN folders_archiv  
 ON folders_archiv.datum= folders.datum  
WHERE folders_archiv.datum = '".$year."-".$month."-".$day."'
```

Comment: Why should he try this? A good answer should explain what's wrong in the original code, and how you corrected it.